# PHP Code not Recognized in CTP file

Tags: php, cakephp

php script is not recognized with  script tags, if I use  then the code runs just fine.

**Works:**

```
<?php $layout->sessionFlash(); ?>
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```
<?$layout->sessionFlash();?>
```

**Works:**

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```
<?=$content_for_layout;?>
```

This is code taken from another website that works correctly on the server but I am trying to get it working on my local wamp server and I am running into this issue. It is only in the .ctp files.

Comment: You have short tags disabled?

Comment: short open tags needed to be turned on through the wamp icon.  changing it int he php.ini file did not work. I had to left click on the wamp icon > 'PHP' > 'PHP Settings' > click 'short open tags'.  Wamp will then reset and it should be checked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like Babiker already said, `short_open_tag` has to be set to `1` in your `php.ini`. But to be on the safe side, you should only use long tags and `echo` in your code, as you cannot be sure if the PHP server you might your application deploy to has short tags enabled.